# JS recursive mergeSort with objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hihi,

My question is simple. I'm trying to implement mergesort but having a limitation with the structure of my project

I have a file called `sort.js`

```
const selSort = require('./selectionSort');
const bubSort = require('./bubbleSort');
const inSort = require('./insertionSort');
const merSort = require('./mergeSort');

const sort = (arr) => {
  const array = arr;
  return {
    ...selSort(array),
    ...bubSort(array),
    ...inSort(array),
    ...merSort(array),
  };
};
```

As you can see I'm trying to implement multiple sort algorithm and make an object

well, now while I started doing the MergeAlgorithm (a recursive sort algorithm) I faced with the problem of the objects in JavaScript

```
const merge = (left, right) => {
  const result = [];
  while (left.length && right.legnth) {
    result.push(left[0] < right[0] ? left.shifth() : right.shifth());
  }
  return [...result, ...left, ...right];
};
const merSort = (array) => ({
  mergeSort: () => {
    if (array.length === 1) {
      return array;
    }
    const middle = Math.floor(array.length);
    const leftArr = array.slice(0, middle);
    const rightArr = array.slice(middle);
    return merge(this(leftArr).mergeSort(), this(rightArr).mergeSort());
  },
});

module.exports = merSort;
```

I cant call `mergeSort()` and pass to it the left and right array without calling itself again.

Is there anyway to solve this?

I tried using `this` but it didn't worked
I think there is no way to achive what I want

Comment: Do you mean that you have to call the function by using merSort.mergeSort(arr) ?

Comment: Why are your returning an Object that has the mergeSort func, instead of executing it directly? In this way you have for sure to recall the merSort to have the func working. Or you can work with constructor function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function?retiredLocale=it

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the spread operator (  ...  ) all the time ? Also why are you reassigning the arr argument to a constant?

This should work just fine

```
const selSort = require('./selectionSort');
const bubSort = require('./bubbleSort');
const inSort = require('./insertionSort');
const merSort = require('./mergeSort');

const sort = (arr) => {
 
  return {
    selSort(arr),
    bubSort(arr),
    inSort(arr),
    merSort(arr),
  };
};
```

Also for the sorting code this should work

```
 function mergeSort(unsortedArray) {
  if (unsortedArray.length <= 1) {
    return unsortedArray;
  }

  const middle = Math.floor(unsortedArray.length / 2);
  const left = unsortedArray.slice(0, middle);
  const right = unsortedArray.slice(middle);    
  return merge(mergeSort(left,), mergeSort(right));
}

function merge(left, right) {
  let resultArray = [],
    leftIndex = 0,
    rightIndex = 0;

 
    while (leftIndex < left.length && rightIndex < right.length) {
      if (left[leftIndex] < right[rightIndex]) {
        resultArray.push(left[leftIndex]);
        leftIndex++;
      } else {
        resultArray.push(right[rightIndex]);
        rightIndex++;
      }
    }
  

  return resultArray
    .concat(left.slice(leftIndex))
    .concat(right.slice(rightIndex));
}

module.exports = mergeSort;
```